# Making a filename truncator in go

Tags: go, filenames

I am new to Go, and I've been trying to make a program that truncates filenames after (and including) the character "-" of all files in its directory. It's not working, and I don't know where I'm going wrong.

```
func changeFilename() {
    file, err := os.Open(".")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed opening directory: %s", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    oldNames, _ := file.Readdirnames(0)

    var s string
    for _, i := range oldNames {
        for _, j := range i {
            for j != '-' {
                k := strconv.QuoteRune(j)
                s += k
                j++
            }
        }
        err := os.Rename(i, s)
        if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to rename: %s", err)
        }
    }
}
```

I expected filenames in the test directory to be changed when I ran the executable, but they didn't. The program builds without any error messages.

Comment: Your innermost for loop is broken. It either never runs at all or never terminates because j doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing your logic to correspond to your description of the problem:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

// changeFilename truncates filenames after (and including) the character "-"
// of all files in the directory. File extensions are preserved.
func changeFilename(dir string) {
    file, err := os.Open(dir)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed opening directory: %s", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    fis, err := file.Readdir(0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed reading directory: %s", err)
    }

    for _, fi := range fis {
        if !fi.Mode().IsRegular() {
            continue
        }
        old := fi.Name()
        ext := filepath.Ext(old)
        for i, r := range old[:len(old)-len(ext)] {
            if r == '-' {
                new := old[:i] + ext
                err := os.Rename(old, new)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatalf("failed to rename: %s", err)
                }
                fmt.Printf("%q %q\n", old, new)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    changeFilename(".")
}
```

Output:

```
"trunc-ate.typ" "trunc.typ"
"hyp-hen.ext" "hyp.ext"
```

Comment: @AtharV: You accepted an answer from `@hmm` which renames more than files. For example, sub-directories. You asked for "all files in the directory."

Answer (score 0):

Your `s` variable should  be moved into the outermost loop since its lifetime should be tied to a single `oldName`. The innermost loop has no exit condition once a non `-` character is encountered. That should be an `if` statement with a corresponding `break` if a `-` is found. As for building up the new filename, you ought to use `+= string(j)` instead of quoting the rune.

```
func changeFilename() {
    file, err := os.Open(".")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed opening directory: %s", err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    oldNames, _ := file.Readdirnames(0)

    for _, i := range oldNames {
        var s string
        for _, j := range i {
            if j != '-' {
                s += string(j)
            } else {
                    break
            }
        }
        err := os.Rename(i, s)
        if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to rename: %s", err)
        }
    }
}
```